# Camel integration with existing web application

Tags: apache-camel

I have a web application providing rest full service and another standalone (jar) application doing soap request response (using camel)

Can someone give me pointers to me for how to integrate the two applications

Specifically around how to kick camel routes when war file is deployed in tomcat, and how to re-run the routes when a specific HTTP request arrives.

I am using camel DSL (xml) and spring.

UPDATE 1:
I have followed [this](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html)

1. Checked that web.xml has following lines:

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
       <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>com.mycompany.server.Binder</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
       <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
   </context-param>


   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
2. Created a /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file and put all my routes and beans in it (btw I have beans.xml file as well in src/main/resources which is getting read by spring).

   ```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans 
          xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
          xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
           http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          ">


     <!--  Camel applicationContext -->
     <!-- this import needed to bring in CXF classes -->
     <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />  

       <bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
           <property name="location"  value="classpath:${env}/my.properties" />
       </bean>

       <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
           <property name="locations">
               <list>
                   <value>classpath:${env}/my.properties</value>
               </list>
           </property>
       </bean>

       <camel:camelContext id="camelContext">
           <camel:contextScan/>
           <camel:template id="serviceConsumerTemplate" defaultEndpoint="direct:start" />
           <camel:threadPoolProfile defaultProfile="true" id="defaultThreadPool" poolSize="10" maxPoolSize="15" />

           <camel:route id="serviceGetAccount">
               <camel:from uri="timer://kickoff?repeatCount=1"/>
               <camel:to uri="bean:serviceGetAccountProcessor" />
               <camel:to uri="bean:serviceRequestHeaderCreator" />
               <camel:to uri="cxf:bean:serviceGetAccountEndpoint?dataFormat=POJO" />
               <camel:to uri="bean:serviceGetAccountResponseProcessor" />
           </camel:route>
       </camel:camelContext>

       <bean id="serviceRequestHeaderCreator" class="com.mycompany.service.soap.SOARequestHeaderCreator">
           <property name="serviceName" value="service" />
           <property name="spnValue" value="${nj.spn}" />
           <property name="securityTokenEnabled" value="true" />
           <property name="sendingApplication" value="NJ SERVICE" />
           <property name="serviceVersion" value="3.0.2" />
           <property name="sendingHost" ref="localHostName"/>
       </bean>

       <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceGetAccountEndpoint"
           address="${request.endpoint}/serviceAccountRequestResponsePT"
           endpointName="s:serviceAccountRequestResponsePort"
           serviceName="s:serviceAccountRequestResponseHTTP"
           xmlns:s="http://soa.mycompany.com/services/service/wsdl/v3"
           serviceClass="com.mycompany.services.service.wsdl.v3.serviceAccountRequestResponsePT"
           loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
       </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

       <bean id="serviceGetAccountProcessor" class="com.mycompany.service.serviceGetAccountProcessor"/>
       <bean id="serviceGetAccountResponseProcessor" class="com.mycompany.service.serviceGetAccountResponseProcessor"/>

   </beans>
   ```
3. Up the logging level of log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=DEBUG

However do not see any camel log lines of routes starting.

**Update 2**:
I was not doing mvn clean generate-sources.
Once I started doing mvn clean and rebuilding the war file, camel kicked in.

Comment: Can you show us the log file? My advice: Start small with the example given at https://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html and then add your additions one by one. By the way: 1) you don't have to configure the Log4j property file if `log4j.properties` is put into the `classes` directory. 2) `${env}/my.properties` looks wrong, just remove `${env}` if `my.properties` is on the top of your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your spring context does not really fire. Make sure it is!
There should be some Spring info log events telling you about this.

Try adding this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```